# Open modal when user clicks on span in visual editor

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

I'm writing a plugin to allow users to insert footnotes in their content.

I've added a button to the toolbar with the media_buttons action. It opens a modal for the user to type the footnote, which is saved elsewhere. Then I add a span to the content with wp.media.editor.insert. Inside the span I just have (F) so that the user sees there is something there. It looks like this: `<span id="qww_footnote_12345" class="qww_footnote">(F)</span>`

Now I need to make it so that the user can click on that span, (F), and open up a modal to be able to edit that footnote.

I tried binding an onClick right after I insert the span, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even give me any errors in the console:

```
jQuery( 'span.qww_footnote' ).click( function() {
        alert( "Edit Footnote!" );
    } );
```

I've been googling and I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. Can someone give me some clues of how to bind events to elements inside the editor?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128791/jquery-javascript-detect-click-event-inside-tinymce